# Catch empty list in While loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a list of subscribers via cursor based pagination. This is my first time using cursor based pagination, so I may be over complicating & I hope you'll identify that if so!

**Here is my function for reference:**

```
def get_subscribers():
    subscribers = [] # Create empty list for appending collected

    url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/subscriptions'

    token = refresh_token(config.refresh_token)

    headers = {
        'Client-id':config.client_id,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
    }

    params = {
        'broadcaster_id':config.channel_id,
    }

    req = requests.request('GET', url, params=params, headers=headers)
    response = req.json()
    subs = response['data']
    next = response['pagination']['cursor']
    for sub in subs:
        print('Appending {0} to Subscriber List.'.format(sub['user_name']))
        subscribers.append(sub)

    while subs is not None:
        params = {
            'broadcaster_id':config.channel_id,
            'after':next
        }

        req = requests.request('GET', url, params=params, headers=headers)
        response = req.json()
        subs = response['data']
        next = response['pagination']['cursor']

        for sub in subs:
            print('Appending {0} to Subscriber List.'.format(sub['user_name']))
            subscribers.append(sub)

    return subscribers
```

**Here's an example response on the first request:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "broadcaster_id": "67961343",
      "broadcaster_name": "xJOKERx",
      "is_gift": false,
      "plan_name": "Channel Subscription (xJOKERx): $24.99 Sub",
      "tier": "3000",
      "user_id": "67961343",
      "user_name": "xJOKERx"
    },
    {
      "broadcaster_id": "67961343",
      "broadcaster_name": "xJOKERx",
      "is_gift": false,
      "plan_name": "Channel Subscription (xJOKERx)",
      "tier": "1000",
      "user_id": "147283917",
      "user_name": "killming"
    },
    {
      "broadcaster_id": "67961343",
      "broadcaster_name": "xJOKERx",
      "is_gift": false,
      "plan_name": "Channel Subscription (xJOKERx)",
      "tier": "1000",
      "user_id": "100417968",
      "user_name": "King_gilbster"
    },
    {
      "broadcaster_id": "67961343",
      "broadcaster_name": "xJOKERx",
      "is_gift": false,
      "plan_name": "Channel Subscription (xJOKERx)",
      "tier": "1000",
      "user_id": "81318617",
      "user_name": "ParagonWing"
    },
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "cursor": "eyJiIjpudWxsLCJhIjp7Ik9mZnNldCI6MjB9fQ"
  }
}
```

**Here is an example response on the "final" page:**

```
{
  "data": [],
  "pagination": {
    "cursor": "eyJiIjp7Ik9mZnNldCI6MTYwfSwiYSI6eyJPZmZzZXQiOjIwMH19"
  }
}
```

So what I'm doing is making my initial request then saying while the list `is not None` continue making requests while using the last cursor for offset.

The problem with this is the list is never `None`. What condition could be met for this to stop the `while` loop?

I am also open to alternatives not requiring a `while` loop.

Comment: Instead of checking if it's None, check if it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking if `sub is None`, check if the list is empty:

```
while subs:   # This checks for both None and empty
    # do things
```

Comment: I knew this would end up being an overlooked simple solution, thank you very much!